# Initializing array members of structs in C

Tags: c

I'm implementing a (direct-mapped) cache with some rows (each containing an `int[ROW_SIZE]` array), simplified as follows:

```
struct Cache {
    int data[ROWS][ROW_SIZE];
};
```

Suppose `struct Cache* cache;` is outside any function and I initialize the cache inside a function:

```
cache = malloc(sizeof(struct Cache));
memset(cache -> data, 0, sizeof(cache -> data[0][0]) * ROWS * ROW_SIZE);
```

Now, I would like to get and set the rows of the cache in functions like:

```
void write_to_row(int row, int* new_data) {
    memcpy(cache -> data[row], new_data, ROW_SIZE);
}

int* read_from_row(int row) {
    return cache -> data[row];
}
```

I never `malloc`ed the `data` member of the `struct Cache`, so I'm wondering if this code will actually persist changes in `cache -> data`, even if it is not currently throwing an error.

When I put `struct Cache* cache;` at the top of the file outside any function, did the compiler automatically take care of putting aside data in memory for the `data` member?

Would your answer be any different if instead I had used the following `struct`?

```
struct Cache {
    int** data;
};
```

Thanks!

Comment: You'd have to `memcpy()` more — `ROW_SIZE * sizeof(cache->data[row][0])`.  Also note that the dot `.` and arrow `->` operators bind very tightly and are never surrounded by spaces.

Comment: "I never malloced the data member of the struct Cache". Yes you did. `cache = malloc(sizeof(Cache));` allocs the whole struct which includes all fields in the struct.

Comment: Does that mean that on `malloc` the `struct Cache` members are also allocated on the heap and can be passed around in functions?

Comment: Yes. It's the same for allocation of any structure - of course enough space would be allocated for all the struct members. What could possibly be the alternative that you seem to have in mind?

Comment: "Would your answer be any different if instead I had used the following struct". The answer is technically the same. Memory is still allocated for `data`. But in that case, only enough memory is allocated for a single pointer. Whereas in the first case enough memory was allocated for the entire array. That is, both cases allocate memory of `sizeof(data)` bytes. But the types are different and hence the size is different for the two cases. I think you are confusing pointers and arrays somewhat.

Comment: OT: If this `cache = malloc(sizeof(Cache));` compiles, you either miss to show us how `Cache` is defined or you use a C++ compiler instead of a C compiler. In C it would need to be `cache = malloc(sizeof(struct Cache));`

Comment: @alk that's right, I forgot to type `struct`.